# How to prove that a particular ideal is the kernel of a ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have to prove that $(1+3i)$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $f:\Bbb{Z}[i]\to \Bbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z}$ defined by $f(a)\to a \mod 10, a\in \Bbb{Z}$, and $f(i)\to 3 \mod 10$.

I know that $(1+3i)$ is mapped to $0\mod 10$. However, how should we prove this is the kernel? For example, $(i^4 -1)$ is also mapped to $0\mod 10$. So should we prove $(i^4 -1)\subseteq (1+3i)$? I suppose it is not possible to prove that $(1+3i)$ is the kernel this way as there might be infinite such ideals which are mapped to $0$ by this homomorphism.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can simplify $i^4-1$. All elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ can be written as $a+bi$, so you only need to go to the first power of $i$ to get all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

As I say in the comments, you can simplify $i^4-1$. All elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ can be written as $a+bi$, so you only need to go to the first power of $i$ to get all the elements.

Perhaps the best way to solve this problem is to note that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a principal ideal domain, so the ideal you want is generated by some single element. Factor $1 + 3i$ into prime factors, and check whether any of these satisfy the given condition. If they don't, then the kernel cannot be bigger than $(1+3i)$!

Answer (score 0):

You know that $(1 + 3i) \subseteq Ker f$. Since Gauss integers are PID and $Ker f$ is an ideal, there must be some generator as well. The only ideals containing $(1 + 3i)$ are the ideals $(1+i)$ and $(2+i)$ (since these are factors of $(1 + 3i)$), which are not in the kernel, hence we're done.

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown is that $(1 + 3i) \subset \text{ker} f$, we'll now prove the other way round, i.e $\text{ker} f \subset (1 + 3i)$. You can also give a direct proof to it, as follow:

1. Firstly, assume that $a + bi \in \text{ker} f$, and our aim is to prove that $a + bi \in (1 + 3i)$, we should make use of this fact (i.e, the fact that $a + bi \in \text{ker} f$) somehow. It's not hard to show that $(a + 3b) \ \vdots \ 10$, so I'll leave this to you.
2. Secondly, you should note that $\dfrac{10}{1 + 3i} \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, this can be proved by a simple manipulation using conjugation. So, in fact, $10 \in (1 + 3i)$.
3. So, what left is to show that $a + bi \in (1 + 3i)$ using the 2 facts above. It's true, because: $a + bi = \underbrace{(a + 3ai)}_{\in (1 + 3i)} + bi - 3ai$. Now, we'll deal with the remaining term, $bi - 3ai = \underbrace{-3ai -9bi}_{\in (10 i) \text{, pay attention to the first fact}} + 10bi$. Can you take it from here?

If you have any questions, just leave a comment below. :)